# React- Root location of Virtual Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, virtual-dom

I cant understand how react's virtual dom remains in memory. Something must has a ref to its root in order to stay in memory. Does anybody know where that root is? Where virtual dom is stored?

Comment: what do you mean by "root" here? The "virtual DOM" is just a data structure representing the content of the page. It's purely up to React internals how these things are done but nothing about "storing it" seems particular complicated - this is after all Javascript rather than C!

Comment: @RobinZigmond For example if you run for a second time, ReactDom.render(....), how react will find the virtual dom to see the new changes?

Comment: You could read the source code for yourself: https://github.com/facebook/react and https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/react-dom

Comment: @Matt Morgan this is not an answer

Comment: No, @Nick, it's just a comment suggesting a place you might start researching the problem.  Good luck!